# Tomcat and JSTL error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jstl

I need some help, please!

I'm having a problem on executing a sample in Eclipse Helios.

I'm working on Liferay 6.1 and Tomcat 7, on a portlet based on Drools.

I read some other posts related with that one but none functioned for me.

This is the error:

```
    Can't process TLD with route [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] and URI [/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld]
```

As I read on other posts I placed JSTL 2.1 libs on WEB-INF/lib folder and I use the build path to tie it to the project but even this the error is still appearing.

And I also added this code to web.xml...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">
```

What I should to solve this?

Thank you so much,

Oriol

Comment: /WEB-INF/tld/c.tld is suspicious. Show us how you declared the taglib in the JSP.

Comment: I don't know why, but I undeploy de portlet and deploy it again and the problem was solved. Thank you so much

Comment: the taglib is that one.. <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>